# Oracle ADF: refresh related rows after transaction

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have an Oracle ADF entity in which there are relationships between the rows which are enforced in the database.

I'll give you a simplified case:

Suppose the attributes of MyEntityImpl are Customer, Month, and Quantity, and Quantity Rank.  Suppose the primary key is (Customer, Month).  Suppose the definition of "Quantity Rank" is that it must be the dense rank of the customer's quantity within the given month.  So, the customer with the highest quantity in the month gets 1, then next highest gets 2, etc.  (Suppose ties are broken by customer name -- it doesn't matter).

The DML for this page is set up such that, when I update any row, the "quantity rank" values of all customers in the given month are immediately recomputed and updated in the database.

So, the key question here is: what is the most natural, simplest, most "ADFish" way to make my ADF page *efficiently* requery and display the updated rows for the entire month whenever any value in the month changes?

For example, the user updates customer #100, month 2017-02 with a quantity of 100.  That will cause some (or even all) of the other customer records in month 2017-02 to get updated "quantity rank" values.  What is the best way to ensure that my ADF page refreshes those other records as well as the record that was actually updated?

#### Update

In the actual problem the "quantity rank" calculation is very involved and requires a lot of other database data, which is why it is done in the database.  So, solutions involving Groovy expressions and what-not are probably not going to be helpful.  I tried including the data required for this calculation in the entity model, so that I could have the ADF page perform the calculation, but the extra data slowed down the page noticeably.  Performance is very important on this page (even more-so than usual).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the ADF BC model updated when the data source changes. You might start by looking at active data sources Docs, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/adv_ads.htm#ADFFD19612). and this [blog](http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2014/01/practical-example-for-adf-active-data.html).

If you mean the ADF Faces page issues a change to the database through the ADF Model and ADF BC layers, you can re-execute the query from the ADF FACES page, using EL to call the Execute operation on the  data control, or refresh the iterator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574019/what-does-the-terms-refresh-and-query-mean-for-an-iterator-binding-mean-in-a#15590628).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I appreciate the time you took (upvote).  I'll have to review the links you sent to see whether they address my problem.  I was looking for an answer along the lines of "iterate through the rowset in the ViewImpl.afterCommit() transaction and call row.refresh for each one" (which is what I am currently trying, but I don't know yet whether it will work.)

Comment: Seems like a lot of manual work - why not just re-execute the query from the DC?

Comment: Because the number of rows that pass the filter condition for display on the page will be in the thousands.  The number of rows that I need to refresh for a single update is about 10.  I am trying to keep the performance in line.